# scanf in C doesn't fail when formatted text doesn't match

Tags: c, scanf

I have hard time understanding how `scanf` in C works. I need the code below to fail with the input `123 foo`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
  int i;
  if (scanf ("%d text", &i) != 1) {
      return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I found in [C refs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) that `scanf` correctly returns the number of successfully assigned arguments (there's 1 specifier in my case), so I can see why the condition in the `if` statement is satisfied (the integer `i` is correctly assigned). However I can't see how I check whether the rest of the argument is satisfied as well (string `text`).

Comment: `scanf` stops converting at the first character that does not match the format. Here, it matches `123` and succeeds. It will then try to match `foo` with `text` but there is no **format specifier** involved. It is a filter. Even if it had matched, `scanf` would still have returned `1` and not `2`. If you want the code to fail, you should `scanf("%d%s")` with a string target argument too, then check that `scanf` returned `2` *and* the string matches by using `strcmp`.

Comment: Another way to do it uses the `%n` 'conversion specification': `int nchars = 0; int i; if (scanf("%d text%n", &i, &nchars) != 1 || nchars == 0) { …badly formed input… }`.  The `%n` conversion is not counted in the successful conversions, hence the test against `1` (for the sole integer input).

Comment: `I have hard time understanding how scanf in C works` !! Truer words have never been spoken.

Comment: Probably the worst thing about `scanf` is that if a numeric input is syntactically correct but out of range of the type, the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to do this manually.

Example if you want to fail only if user inputs `"123 foo"`

```
int main () 
{
  int i;
  char s[100];
  if (scanf ("%d %99s", &i, s) == 2 && !strcmp(s, "foo") && i == 123) 
  {
      return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think the user should be allowed to enter any number, but the text that follows should be `text` and _not_ `foo`.  Your condition should probably be ``scanf(…) != 2 || strcmp(s, "text") != 0)`` (with no immediate need to validate `i`).  Returning `1` from `main()` indicates failure; returning `0` indicates success.  I think an error message would be appropriate too, printed to standard error, of course.

Answer (score 5):

Although it is possible to use the `%n` specifier to determine the number of characters read so far, the problem is that this will not increase the assignment count, which is returned by `scanf`. Therefore, it is not easy to tell whether `scanf` actually wrote to the argument corresponding to the `%n` specifier or whether a matching failure occurred beforehand, causing this argument to remain untouched by `scanf`.

This problem can be solved by initializing the value of the variable to a value that can be distinguished from a value that `scanf` would write to it. In the example below, I initialize the variable to the value `-1`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int i;
    int chars_read = -1;

    if (
        scanf( "%d text%n", &i, &chars_read ) != 1
        ||
        chars_read == -1
    )
    {
        printf( "Bad input!\n" );
        return 1;
    }

    printf( "Good input.\n" );
    return 0;
}
```

In this program, we do not actually need to know the number of characters that were read (which is the primary purpose of the `%n` specifier). Instead, we are only using the `%n` specifier to determine whether it was reached or whether a matching failure occurred beforehand.

Comment: See my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73964059/scanf-in-c-doesnt-fail-when-formatted-text-doesnt-match#comment130597151_73964059).  If you initialize the variable that will hold the character count (to `0`, for example), you can tell whether it was assigned because the value will still be zero if the code fails to match `text` — that's guaranteed by the standard.  So, using `%n` is feasible. All the possible ways of dealing with it are rather ugly.  I'd probably use `fgets()` or POSIX `getline()` to read a line and then analyze it with `sscanf()` (but it's ugly too)!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: That is a very good idea on how to use the `%n` specifier. I believe I have successfully implemented it.